# how to block a process in a web application only if the execution parameters are the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form with 4 dropdownlists and a search button that obtains a list from the database using the values ​​of the selected dropdownlist as filters, what I need is that if user A and B select the same values ​​of the dropdownlist, only 1 of them can work with the list obtained from the database. What would be the best way to work this?

```
//Get employee list

List<Entity.Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Entity.Employee>();

lstEmployees = Logic.Employee.getEmployees(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, DropDownList2.SelectedValue, DropDownList3.SelectedValue, DropDownList4.SelectedValue);

foreach(Employee emp in lstEmployees)
{
     //single process per user required
}

//release single process
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options depending on the environment you are using

1) If you are hosting it on a single server
You can use the application pool Application[Key1 + Key2 + Key3] as a way to track if someone is already working on that combination if not, let them continue.

2) If you are hosting it on a web farm
Use a database (or a shared storage somewhere ex: network share) to track the locking of those parameter combination similar to #1

Obviously #1 is easier/faster

## 2 is scalable

```
//Get employee list

List<Entity.Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Entity.Employee>();

lstEmployees = Logic.Employee.getEmployees(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, DropDownList2.SelectedValue, DropDownList3.SelectedValue, DropDownList4.SelectedValue);

foreach(Employee emp in lstEmployees)
{
    String MyKey = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
    if(Application[MyKey]==null || Application[MyKey]=""){
        //single process per user required
    }
}

//release single process
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Employee is a class that you have access to?

The simplest solution I can picture here would be to incorporate a boolean field titled something like "isCheckedOut" and simply check for this value before allowing any data modification.

This solution doesn't really mechanically "lock-down" the code, but depending on how you're accessing it, this sort of quick check could be a very simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

I write the code like this

string sProcesoUnico = ddlCompania.SelectedValue + ddlNomina.SelectedValue + ddlPeriodo.SelectedValue + ddlClaveMovi.SelectedValue;

```
                        if (Application[sProcesoUnico].ToString() == "" || Application[sProcesoUnico] == null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                // Process
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                throw;
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                Application[sProcesoUnico] = ""; //release process 
                            }
                        }
```

It´s ok the way that I  release the Application State?